# CSS+Javascript swap different background image

Tags: javascript, html, css, background

I want to change at least three banners (background image) by a click.  it can be swapped two banners, but how to swap more than three images in order. Also, i want to have transition effect when i swap the images. Can anyone help.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#next-section").click(function(){
    $("#banner").css("background-image", "url('images/top8.jpg')");
  });
});
```

```css
#banner {
  background-image: url("images/top7.jpg");
  background-position: center center;
  background-size: cover;
  height: 30em;
  text-align: left;
  position: relative;
  -ms-overflow-style: scrollbar;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.0.0.js"></script>
<div id="logo" style="height:200px">
  <section id="banner"  >
    <div id="back-section">
      <a class="back"><span></span></a>
    </div><!-- /.next-section -->
    <div id="next-section" >
      <a class="next"><span></span></a>
    </div><!-- /.next-section -->
    <div class="inner">
      <div class="logo"><h12><img style="vertical-align:middle" src="images/hi5logo.png" alt="" width="50">  Interactive Game </h12> </div>
    </div>
  </section>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've set up a script so that your backgrounds are cycled from an array, and when the last background is reached, the first one is set as the next one.

```
var arrayOfBackgrounds=["http://placehold.it/300x200","http://placehold.it/222x222","http://placehold.it/333x333"];
var currentBackground=0;
$("#next-section").click(function(){
    $("#banner").css("background-image", "url('"+arrayOfBackgrounds[currentBackground]+"')");
        currentBackground++;
        currentBackground=currentBackground % arrayOfBackgrounds.length;
}
```

The currentBackground is the index of the background, and the line that says `currentBackground%arrayOfBackgrounds.length` divides the index by the number of possible backgrounds and returns the remainder. 
This is how the modulus operator works:

```
0 % 3 = 0
1 % 3 = 1
2 % 3 = 2
3 % 3 = 0 (the remainder here is 0)
...
```

You can find the complete codepen along with animations [here](https://codepen.io/pghiran/pen/QEgWJm)

Comment: setTimeout(nexttobackground(),5000);   i try to set a timer to loop the image but it does not work

Comment: The function you are looking for is probably setInterval. See the example here: https://codepen.io/pghiran/pen/QEgWJm

Comment: thank you   and if i want to have transition or animation when looping image , in css where should i add to?  because my background-image is inside #banner

Comment: well in this case, I think something like 
        `$("#banner").css("left", "100%").animate({
            "left": "0"
        }, 500);` would be the easiest way to implement an animation. See codepen here https://codepen.io/pghiran/pen/VjWYaP

Comment: how powerful you are. thank for advice. these bother me long time

Comment: Glad I could help. If this solved your question can you please mark it as answered? (click the checkbox near the answer, helps with sorting things out)